# How to store different input prices for one product?

Tags: mysql

I'm in the process of creating an inventory monitoring program and I've come across a problem. I will try to describe my problem below.

When calculating the profit on sale, I take the purchase price from the database. The problem arises when -> I bought 10x GOODS_X for the different prices: 1x 10,00 USD ("index" 1), 3x 12,00 USD ("index" 2-4), 6x 15,00 USD ("index" 5-10).

The selling price is 20,00 USD.

I want to receive calculated profits for specific "index" after sold like this: 1x 20,00 - 10,00 -> 10,00 profit, 3x 20,00 - 12,00 -> 8,00 profit, 6x 20,00 - 15,00 -> 5,00 profit.

How can I store different purchase prices in the database without averaging them?

PS. I am using "products" table where every specific product has just one record, and one price column. "

Answer (score 0):

I dont really see the problem if you already indexed them separately.

so just note the different prices.

| id | product | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | prodName | 10,00 |
| 1 | prodName | 12,00 |
| 2 | prodName | 12,00 |
| 3 | prodName | 12,00 |
| 4 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 5 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 6 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 7 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 8 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 9 | prodName | 15,00 |
| 10 | prodName | 15,00 |

I hope I could help and didn't misunderstand your problem

Comment: I writted about my table in PS ->PS. I am using "products" table where every specific product has just one record, and one price column. I have just one record for a specific item. I don't have 10 records for 10 pieces, because some items are over 100 pcs.

Comment: ah ok, then you could nest the information. So instead of just one price you can have an array inside the data-field that lists the prices and correlates it to the number of items you have for that price. was that clear or do I need to clarify in a new table with an example?

Comment: its one more step to access the info after that tho, and it decreases performance a little